# How to disable edit button for a row in listview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

Here is my html code

```
<ItemTemplate>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sysID")%>'></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Labelpar" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("parameters")%>'></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("value")%>'></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text='Edit' CommandName="Edit" />
        </td>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I have 3 rows (a,b,c) in my column. How can I disable "Edit" button for row a?

by "disable" I mean user should not be able to click

Comment: are you using **ItemCreated** event?

Comment: at what event/in which condition you need to disable button ?

Comment: `where sysID = a` @wingedpanther

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but definitely something like this

```
<asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text='Edit' Enabled='<%# (Eval("sysID")=="a")?False:True %>' CommandName="Edit" />
```

Comment: could you write correct syntax, it says "expression expected"